# Dynamic ajax category child dropdown

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using GF to create a filter. Some part of the work is done.

What I need to do now is allow 3 or 4 dropdowns to be populated dynamically.
I'm using the code providade in topic in http://goo.gl/hU31iK

I already made the queries on my table, but I'm having some difficulties, as described below:

First, my form ID is 1.
My first dropdown's ID is input_1_6
Second is input_1_4
Third is input_1_5
Fourth is input_1_7

That said, using the code in topic above, the values for input_1_4 is being loaded after choosing some value in input_1_6, but it isn't actually populating the dropdown input_1_4 (javascript alerts the values loaded, but the dropdown is empty).

Plus, any ideas on how to create the third and fourth filters, based on choices?
-- Field input_1_6 loads
-- Choosing some value in input_1_6 populates input_1_4 (based on value in input_1_6).
-- Choosing some value in input_1_4 populates input_1_5 (based on value in input_1_4).
-- Choosing some value in input_1_5 populates input_1_7 (based on value in input_1_5).
-- Choosing some value in input_1_7 and click submit form will do my stuff.

Thanks!